# Showing lineleft node on collapse

Tags: javascript, html, charts, google-visualization

Hi I am using google visualization org chart to create org chart which is having SharPoint as source it work fine and but whenever  collapse it show small left node
and want to remove this  extra left line node if it collapse ,
when  tried change CSS it goes for all not for particular node

Below is my full code where first i mentioned style and to meet company standard modified style

Added below line to get Sharepoint

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', drawChart);

    });
```

It work as expected but for first node for all other nodes its not wokring as expected while debugging it goes to step but failed to add class

```
    <style>
.no-border {
  border-left: none !important;
}
img {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

#sideNavBox{
    
    display:none!important;
}

#s4-titlerow
{
    display:none!important;
}
    .loader {
        border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
        border-radius: 50%;
        border-top: 16px solid #3498db;
        width: 120px;
        height: 120px;
        -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite; /* Safari */
        animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
    }

/* Safari */
    @-webkit-keyframes spin {
        0% {
            -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        }

        100% {
            -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        }
    }

    @keyframes spin {
        0% {
            transform: rotate(0deg);
        }

        100% {
            transform: rotate(360deg);
        }
    }

    table {
        border-collapse: separate !important;
    }

    .google-visualization-orgchart-node {
        background: #eb3c96 !important;
        border: 1px solid #eb3c96 !important;
        padding-bottom: 15px !important;
        padding-top: 15px !important;
        width: 165px !important;
    }
   
    .google-visualization-orgchart-linebottom {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #e61717 !important;
    }
   
  .google-visualization-orgchart-lineleft {
        border-left: 1px solid #e61717 !important;
    }
    .google-visualization-orgchart-node {
        color: white;
        
    }
    .google-visualization-orgchart-lineright {
        border-right: 1px solid #e61717 !important;
    }
 
        
    .plus {
        position: relative;
        top: 0px;
        height: 24px;
        cursor: pointer;

    }
    


</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', drawChart);
        
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">  
google.load('visualization', '1', { packages: ['table', 'orgchart'] });
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

     var collListItem =null;
     var dataArray = []; 
    function drawChart() {

        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext("https://test.sharepoint.com/sites/TEST1/");
        var oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();
        var oList = oWebsite.get_lists().getByTitle('OrgChart');
        var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
        camlQuery.set_viewXml("<View><Query></Query></View>");
        collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
        clientContext.load(collListItem);
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySucceeded, onQueryFailed)

    }
    function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {

        var listItemInfo = '';

        var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();
        while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {

            var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
            dataArray.push([oListItem.get_item('Emp_Id'), oListItem.get_item('M_Member'), oListItem.get_item('F_Manager'),oListItem.get_item('Super_Visor_ID'),oListItem.get_item('Steam'),oListItem.get_item('V_Team'),
            oListItem.get_item('Photo').$1_1])

        }
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

        data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
        data.addColumn('string', 'Manager');
        var i = 0

        for (i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++) {

            var Emp_Id = dataArray[i][0].toString();
            var TM_Member = dataArray[i][1];
            var FM_Manager = dataArray[i][2];
            var Super_ID = dataArray[i][3] != null ? dataArray[i][3].toString() : "TEST";
            var SUteam = dataArray[i][4] ;
            var VO_Team = dataArray[i][5] ;
            var photo = dataArray[i][6];;
            
            data.addRows([[{
                v: Emp_Id,
                f: VO_Team + '<br /><b>' + TM_Member + '<br /><b><div></div><img  border-radius="25px" height="50px" width="50px" src="' + photo + '" />'
                
            }, Super_ID]]);
        }
        var chart = new google.visualization.OrgChart($("#chartOrg")[0]);
        google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function () {
            // get the row of the node clicked
            var selection = chart.getSelection();
            var row = selection[0].row;
            // get a list of all collapsed nodes
            var collapsed = chart.getCollapsedNodes();
            // if the node is collapsed, we want to expand it
            // if it is not collapsed, we want to collapse it
            var collapse = (collapsed.indexOf(row) == -1);
       chart.collapse(row, collapse);   
            // clear the selection so the next click will work properly
            chart.setSelection();
            
        });

 // collapse
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'collapse', function (props) {
  // determine if collapsed
  if (props.collapsed) {
    // remove border from last node
    var nodes = document.getElementsByClassName('google-visualization-orgchart-lineleft');
    nodes[nodes.length - 1].classList.add('no-border');
  } else {
    // add border to all nodes
    var nodes = document.getElementsByClassName('no-border');
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(nodes, function(node) {
      node.classList.remove('no-border');
    });
  }
});

        chart.draw(data, { allowHtml: true, allowCollapse: true });
       
    }

    function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

        alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() +

            '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());

    }
</script> 
<div id="chartOrg">  
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you create a demo which shows the problem?

Comment: @SalmanA
 I used this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/oxzabtyg/ and added the above css if you see in  collapse it shows small node which  want to hide if  try to remove css it remove for all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the chart's `collapse` event to determine when a node has been collapsed or expanded.
use a custom class to hide the "leftline" when collapsed.
remove the custom class when expanded.

```
// collapse
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'collapse', function (props) {
  // determine if collapsed
  if (props.collapsed) {
    // remove border from last node
    var nodes = document.getElementsByClassName('google-visualization-orgchart-lineleft');
    nodes[nodes.length - 1].classList.add('no-border');
  } else {
    // add border to all nodes
    var nodes = document.getElementsByClassName('no-border');
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(nodes, function(node) {
      node.classList.remove('no-border');
    });
  }
});
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages:['orgchart']
}).then(function drawChart() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
  data.addColumn('string', 'Manager');
  data.addColumn('string', 'ToolTip');
  // For each orgchart box, provide the name, manager, and tooltip to show.
  data.addRows([
    [{v:'Mike', f:'Mike<div><a href="http://www.google.com">google</a></div>'},'', 'The President'],
    [{v:'Jim', f:'Jim<div><a href="http://www.google.com">google</a></div>'},'Mike', 'VP'],
    ['Alice', 'Mike', ''],
    ['Bob', 'Alice', ''],
    [{v:'John', f:'John<div><a href="http://www.google.com">google</a></div>'},'Bob', 'VP'],
    ['Carol', 'Bob', ''],
    [{v:'Jake', f:'Jake<div><a href="http://www.google.com">google</a></div>'},'John', 'VP']
  ]);
  // Create the chart.
  var chart = new google.visualization.OrgChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

  // selection
  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function () {
    // get the row of the node clicked
    var selection = chart.getSelection();
    var row = selection[0].row;
    // get a list of all collapsed nodes
    var collapsed = chart.getCollapsedNodes();
    // if the node is collapsed, we want to expand it
    // if it is not collapsed, we want to collapse it
    var collapse = (collapsed.indexOf(row) == -1);
    chart.collapse(row, collapse);
    // clear the selection so the next click will work properly
    chart.setSelection();
  });

  // collapse
  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'collapse', function (props) {
    // determine if collapsed
    if (props.collapsed) {
      // remove border from last node
      var nodes = document.getElementsByClassName('google-visualization-orgchart-lineleft');
      nodes[nodes.length - 1].classList.add('no-border');
    } else {
      // add border to all nodes
      var nodes = document.getElementsByClassName('no-border');
      Array.prototype.forEach.call(nodes, function(node) {
        node.classList.remove('no-border');
      });
    }
  });

  // Draw the chart, setting the allowHtml option to true for the tooltips.
  chart.draw(data, {allowHtml:true, allowCollapse:true});
});
```

```css
.no-border {
  border-left: none !important;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: it works in fiddle but when i added in my actual code its not working it only work for first node other node it does not work

Comment: I suppose I would need to see the actual code, or are there any error messages in the console?

Comment: I added full code in description it work for first node but not for others

Comment: I just notice nodes are removing but different places not the one which is collapsed

Comment: thanks for the update, but I think a sample of the data might be necessary, in order to re-create the problem...